# Not getting all records in MySQL in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a WordPress site that has a MySQL database. I created a custom table to create this page https://www.my-pocket.cc/test-store-list/

I am creating a C# desktop application to change the tables. The problem is under the site name I am only getting the last record not the two of them.

I am using the MySqlDataReader. I copied the select statement into MySQL and get the right answers (see SQL select statement). I also included the output I am getting and the code.

[SQL select statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtQ9w.jpg)

[C# output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DekI1.jpg)

```
        string connStr = "server=127.0.0.1;user=root;database=mypocket;port=3306;password=green2Apple#";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        conn.Open();

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select Heading_id,Heading_Name, Heading_Order,Group_Class from button_headings order by Heading_Order", conn);

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string connStr2 = "server=127.0.0.1;user=root;database=mypocket;port=3306;password=green2Apple#";
                MySqlConnection conn2 = new MySqlConnection(connStr2);
                conn2.Open();
                txtOutput.Text += $"{reader.GetString("Heading_Name")} ";
                string StoreId = $"{reader.GetString("Group_Class")}";
                txtOutput.Text += "\r\n";
                try
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("select Site_Url, FullName FROM siteinfo  where StoreId = " + StoreId + " and showsite = 0", conn2);
                    MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                    txtOutput.Text += "\t";
                    if (reader1.Read()) {

                        while (reader1.Read())

                        {
                            txtOutput.Text += "\t";
                            txtOutput.Text += $"{reader1.GetString("FullName")}";
                            txtOutput.Text += "\r\n";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txtOutput.Text += "\t";
                        txtOutput.Text += "No Records";
                        txtOutput.Text += "\r\n";
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error Getting Records" + ex.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Getting Records" + ex.ToString());
        }

        btnReturn.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann's objection about SQL injection isn't as worrisome in this case because it's your own desktop application, but please do check your site for this pattern. Cite: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Why not use ORM like EF? It will solve the injection potential and allow LINQ for the query logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `read()` twice, but discarding one result:

```csharp
if (reader1.Read()) {
    while (reader1.Read())
```

The *if* statement will read the first record, and then the *while* loop will read the second (and any subsequent) records and actually display them.

I would get rid of the *if* statement, and create boolean variable that is set to true when entering the loop. If the variable is false, then you know that no records have been retrieved and you can display the message for no records found.

```csharp
bool hasRecords = false;

while (reader1.Read())
{
    hasRecords = true;
    txtOutput.Text += "\t";
    txtOutput.Text += $"{reader1.GetString("FullName")}";
    txtOutput.Text += "\r\n";
}

if(!hasReords)
{
    txtOutput.Text += "\t";
    txtOutput.Text += "No Records";
    txtOutput.Text += "\r\n";
}
```